# Populate value from a different row when conditions are matched

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to solve the following in `dplyr`. In a table, find the same combination of people and dates, but in reverse order.

For example:

Person A meets Person B on 11-27-2019 - then there should be another row where Person B meets Person A on the same date.

When this happens, I'd like the "Value Local" to populate on the "Value Traveling". I'd like to find a `dplyr` solution for this. Below is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Person.Local <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")

Person.Travel <- c("C", "J", "K", "B", "I", "C", "K", "V", "A", "P", "A", "Z", "H")

Date <- c("2019-10-31", "2019-10-14", "2019-10-13", "2019-10-12", "2019-10-12", "2019-10-18", "2019-10-21", "2019-10-22", "2019-10-12", "2019-10-29", "2019-10-31", "2019-04-04", "2019-10-31")

Value.Local <- c(1,4,5,5,7,9,7,5,3,8, 7,4,5)

db <- tibble(Person.Local, Date, Person.Travel, Value.Local)

db
```

Edit: After some back and forth, ended up solving it like this:

```
a <- db %>%
  mutate(conc = paste(Person.Local,Date,Person.Travel)) %>%
  select(a.Person.Local = Person.Local, a.Date = Date, a.Person.Travel = Person.Travel, a.Value.Local = Value.Local, conc)

b <- db %>%
  mutate(conc = paste(Person.Travel,Date,Person.Local)) %>%
  select(b.Person.Local = Person.Local, b.Date = Date, b.Person.Travel = Person.Travel, b.Value.Local = Value.Local, conc)

full_join(a,b) %>%
  select(Local = a.Person.Local, Date = a.Date, Travel = a.Person.Travel, Value = a.Value.Local, Value.Travel = b.Value.Local)
```

Comment: Based on your example, what would be the desired result? It looks like person A and B met on 2019-10-12, so would there be a new column of `Value.Traveling` to contain 3 from `Value.Local`?

Comment: Correct. A new column should be created (Value.Travel) that will find the value from value.local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of joins should work:

```
db %>% left_join(
  db %>% inner_join(db,
                   by=c("Person.Local"="Person.Travel", 
                        "Person.Travel"="Person.Local",
                        "Date"="Date"), suffix=c("",".y")) %>%
    rename(Value.Travel=Value.Local.y), 
  by=c("Person.Local"="Person.Local", 
       "Person.Travel"="Person.Travel",
       "Date"="Date", "Value.Local"))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   Person.Local Date       Person.Travel Value.Local Value.Travel
   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 A            2019-10-31 C                       1            7
 2 A            2019-10-14 J                       4           NA
 3 A            2019-10-13 K                       5           NA
 4 A            2019-10-12 B                       5            3
 5 A            2019-10-12 I                       7           NA
 6 B            2019-10-18 C                       9           NA
 7 B            2019-10-21 K                       7           NA
 8 B            2019-10-22 V                       5           NA
 9 B            2019-10-12 A                       3            5
10 B            2019-10-29 P                       8           NA
11 C            2019-10-31 A                       7            1
12 C            2019-04-04 Z                       4           NA
13 C            2019-10-31 H                       5           NA
```

---

By the way, you should create data like this to prevent warnings about factor levels:

```
db <- tibble(Person.Local, Date, Person.Travel, Value.Local)
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Josedv for reminding me about the Date they met. ^_^

Comment: Thank you. Does this account for the date? As they may meet again at a different date

Comment: OP didn't mention this. I will update. Thanks. :) :)

Comment: Oh, but you did mention this. Sorry !  Anyway, let me know if it works... I'll test it on more data...

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It would show value.local on value.travel columns, but it would not cross them.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain more and provide an example where my code doesn't work? Thanks. ☺

Comment: See the reprex on my post (i edit it to add Person C). When running your solution, the value in Value.Travel column is exactly the same as the value on the Value.Local column. In that example, when A meets B on 2019-10-12 Value.Local is 5, but Value.Travel should be 3 and not 5. Because 3 is Value.Local when B meets A on 2019-10-12. Sorry it's a bit confusing. Unfortunately I am not sure how to add an image as part of this comment

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Please see revised version and let me know if this works. :)